# Editing a question to add a second part

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/revisions/1606/3) has been edited to add a second part. It is a homework question and the second part follows on from the first, so they are related but seem like distinct questions. The second part was added after an answer came in for the first part.

When is a multi part question acceptable in a single post, and when should the parts be posted as separate questions?

Comment: (Note that I've rolled back the edit to avoid answers coming in to the second part while this is being discussed. You can see the second part in the edit history.)

Answer (score 2):

[This Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/246175) discusses exit strategies for *chameleon questions*. [@tvanfosson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43485/246175) writes

> Generally as long as the OP is still trying to solve the original problem or something closely related, i.e., my answer still makes sense, I'll keep helping.

which, in my opinion, should be the answer to when a question should be stopped from morphing further: **The original problem should stay the same.** And the next problem that occurs when the original one is solved, should be posted as a new question.